# How to achieve delivery notifications using XEP-0198 correctly?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am using XEP-0198 to get delivery notifications from the server for messages the client is sending out. However, it is getting very convoluted because of some issues I am facing.

The message ack from the server sends only a stanza count in the `h` attribute but not a `message_id`. Something like this:

```
a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='3'
```

The problem is if the client tries to send some messages when stream is not connected, the count goes out of sync and I have to make an estimate for what stanza count I should receive on the next ack request on the client side.

Is it possible to receive back a `message_id` pulled from the actual message that was sent? If this is not implemented currently, could someone suggest the changes that would be required on the ejab server that would make it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "the count goes out of sync"? Which implementation do you use client side? For example Smack has [Stanza Acknowledged Listeners](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnection.html#addStanzaAcknowledgedListener-org.jivesoftware.smack.StanzaListener-) which you could use.

Comment: I am using jabber-Net. As far as I could find there was no support for stream management. I am reading raw XML messages directly.